# In C# how to retrieve data from access where double query is needed

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

i've been programming for school for a couple of months now and this is the first time working with c# with a database. The problem that I have is that I want to get data from the access database what only can be retrieved with using a query in a query and after that i want to put that data in a listbox

I got the database code by searching on the internet and haven't had problems with it so far (but perhaps im wrong with that and is that the fault for the problems) but whenever i try to execute the code there is something wrong with the query. Nothing shows up in the listbox. I'm probably making some stupid mistake

database consists of:
Behandelingen: ID, BehandelingID, Behandeling, Bevoegdheid
Patiënt-Behandeling: ID, PersoonID, BehandelingID

in form:  OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection();

before try:listBox1.Items.Clear();

```
        try
        {  OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
            string q = "select BehandelingID from [Behandelingen] where BehandelingID = (select BehandelingID from [Patiënt-Behandeling] where PersoonID =  '" + textBoxUsername.Text + "')";



            command.CommandText = q;
            connection.Open();
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            { while (reader.Read())
                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add(reader["Behandeling"].ToString());
                }

            }
            reader.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }

        catch (Exception a)
        {
            connection.Close();
            MessageBox.Show(a.Message.ToString());

        }
```

Comment: Have you tested the exact query directly in Access? You always make sure your query works by itself before you put it in code.

Comment: What columns are you trying to read?

Comment: Unless the inner SELECT returns exactly 1 BehandelingID, you need to use `IN` instead of `=`

Comment: It's working! I tried it out in access and got a code that is working: SELECT Behandelingen.BehandelingID AS Behandelingen_BehandelingID, Behandelingen.Behandeling, [Patiënt-Behandeling].PersoonID, [Patiënt-Behandeling].BehandelingID AS [Patiënt-Behandeling_BehandelingID]
FROM [Patiënt-Behandeling] RIGHT JOIN Behandelingen ON [Patiënt-Behandeling].[BehandelingID] = Behandelingen.[BehandelingID];
Thanks you so much for the tips :D

Comment: I took the wrong link :I I meant this code:  " SELECT Behandelingen.BehandelingID AS Behandelingen_BehandelingID, Behandelingen.Behandeling, [Patiënt-Behandeling].PersoonID, [Patiënt-Behandeling].BehandelingID AS[Patiënt-Behandeling_BehandelingID] FROM[Patiënt-Behandeling] RIGHT JOIN Behandelingen ON[Patiënt-Behandeling].[BehandelingID] = Behandelingen.[BehandelingID] WHERE PersoonID = '" + textBoxUsername.Text + "'";

Answer (score 0):

you want to get the Behandeling values but you are selecting only BehandelingID the selection command must be like this :

try
 {  OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;
            string q = "select BehandelingID,Behandeling from [Behandelingen] where BehandelingID = (select BehandelingID from [Patiënt-Behandeling] where PersoonID =  '" + textBoxUsername.Text + "')";

```
        command.CommandText = q;
        connection.Open();
        reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        if (reader.HasRows)
        { while (reader.Read())
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(reader["Behandeling"].ToString());
            }

        }
        reader.Close();
        connection.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception a)
    {
        connection.Close();
        MessageBox.Show(a.Message.ToString());

    }
```

but I highly recommend that you use command parameters for information about that you could check this [MSDN page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)